# NSTimer not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

I have set up an NSTimer which after one second should perform a instance method called animate

My code looks like this:

```
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(animate) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    [timer fire];
```

This code is put into a touchesBegan method. The method DOES GET CALLED but not after one second it just immediately gets called. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call [timer fire] it immediately fires the message to the receiver.  You just need to remove that line.

Answer (score 4):

You've scheduled a timer and normally that should automatically invoke after 1.0 seconds, but you follow up with a `[timer fire]` call and that is immediately firing the timer and sending a message to the selector.

[Look at the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/fire).

Answer (score 4):

Delete [timer fire];
That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Calling fire causes the message to be sent to its target immediately. See the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/fire).